# AS3 - Autocrop Technique?

Tags: actionscript-3, bitmapdata

I'd like to know if anybody knows of a good and preferably quick technique for auto cropping images (i.e. BitmapDatas), similar to how GIMP does it? This basically means cropping an image to remove as much unnecessary background as possible, so that all you have left is a rectangle which contains the actual image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at BitmapData's [getColorBoundsRect()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#getColorBoundsRect%28%29) method which does that for you if you pass the correct arguments.

Also have a look at [PlasticSturgeon's excellent article](http://plasticsturgeon.com/2010/09/as3-get-visible-bounds-of-transparent-display-object/) explaining to use the function.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks! I can't believe I didn't look for it myself. It's also blazingly fast which is perfect.